# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when attempting to run a jar file

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I was trying to run a jar file, and got this error

```
sugar@cube:~/Downloads$ java -jar test.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2387)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:746)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1857)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:310)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2392)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:808)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1893)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1387)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1386)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:622)
```

I was thinking that I had jdk-headless and tried re-installing it, but the error persists. I'm running openjdk 16.0.1 on Linux mint.

Any help is greatly appreciated :p

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/674579/libawt-xawt-so-libxext-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-di might help

Comment: I have a headless system where that library is present. Does that file exists on your system?

Comment: Check with: `ldd /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so` what might be wrong.